# Express req.body is empty when data is submitted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building an API with Node.js, Express.js and MongoDB. When I submit the form and use the `req` object in the server controller, the `req.body` object is empty. I have read all the other questions related and tried almost all answers, but the error remains.

[image: This is where the req.body object is supposed to contain the form data]

I don't know if something is wrong, but I have already tried everything, if someone has an answer I will really appreciate it.
This is the link to the Github repo, to the file where the controller is.

[Link to the Github repo where the controller is](https://github.com/smoothness/soursys/blob/master/app_server/controllers/documents.js)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you added a bodyParser ?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: Yes @adeneo body-parser module is added in app.js https://github.com/smoothness/soursys/blob/master/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help, the JS code was fine, it was a newby error on the HTML form, I omitted the "name" attributes on the form controls, that's why the `req.body` object was empty.